# How can I embed a form (scaffold) into a index page using ROR?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding

I have created a scaffold called Contacts and gave it the entries

name:string phone:string  email:string

I want the form visible on the index page for the app user to submit.

Currently the blank form is located in localhost:3000/contacts/new 
then after submission, the app displays the submitted information.

First, How can I embed the form into the index page ?

index.html.erb

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Contacts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= contact.name %></td>
        <td><%= contact.email %></td>
        <td><%= contact.phone %></td>
        <td><%= contact.message %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', contact %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(contact) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contact, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= render 'contacts/form'  %> 
<%= link_to "Apple", {:controller => 'contacts', :action => 'apple'} %>
<%= link_to 'New Contact', new_contact_path %>
```

_form.html.erb

```html
<%= form_for(contact) do |f| %>
  <% if contact.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contact from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %>
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

contacts_controller.rb

```html
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contact, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /contacts
  # GET /contacts.json
  def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
    
  end

  # GET /contacts/1
  # GET /contacts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /contacts/new
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  # GET /contacts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /contacts
  # POST /contacts.json
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @root_path, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /contacts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contacts/1
  # DELETE /contacts/1.json
  def destroy
    @contact.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contact
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :message)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your form is saved as a partial you can add 
<%= render 'form' %> to the index page. With 'form' being replaced with the actual form path.

Comment: Its giving an error -
undefined local variable or method `contact'

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
<%= render partial: "contacts/form", locals: { contact: @contacts } %>
```